# Characterize functions that are integrable with respect to all probability measures

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, functional-analysis

Let $\mathsf{Prob}$ denote the collection of all probability measures on the $\sigma$-algebra of all Lebesgue-measurable subsets of the real numbers, i.e., $\mathsf{Prob}$ denotes the set of all normalized and countably additive functions on the Lebesuge-$\sigma$-algebra with values in $[0, 1]$.

1. How can one characterize the vector space of real-valued functions $f$ which are Lebesgue-integrable with respect to *all* measures $\mu \in \mathsf{Prob}$:
   $$V:=\{f : \int f \ d\mu < \infty \text{ for all } \mu \in \mathsf{Prob} \}$$
   In other words: which are the functions which have a finite expectation with respect to all probability measures?
   For instance, $V$ contains all bounded continuous functions. However, not every function in $V$ is bounded and continuous.
2. Is there a natural topology on $V$? Is it Banach with respect to it?
3. How does the answer change when we require the $m$-th non-central moment to be finite as well, i.e. $\int f^m d\mu < \infty$ as well?
4. How does the answer change when we relax the condition that the measures be countably additive to finitely additive?
   This is a weaker condition so that there are more measures, so that $V$ will become smaller. Then, there are "esoteric" probability measures to take into account, such as the translation-invariant one, which exists thanks to the amenability of the topological group of real numbers and the axiom of choice.
5. Where can one read up the relevant "duality theory"?

For all questions (except the last one): Which is the shortest proof/reference?

EDIT: As Friedrich Philipp has pointed out, the functions in $V$ are necessarily bounded. I would therefore like to extend the question and ask:

6. How do the answers to all questions above (except 4. and 5.) change when we let $\mathsf{Prob}$ be **just the Gaussian measures** (with any mean and non-zero variance)? In that case, $V$ contains all polynomials, if $m=1$, so that the answer gets more interesting. In general, given a set of probability measures, how does one determine the associated "dual" space $V$?

Comment: In fact, $V$ contains all bounded measurable functions. But why is $\int |f|\,d\mu < \infty$ not required? Otherwise, $\int f\,d\mu$ is not even defined.

Comment: Right, it's not defined otherwise. I changed the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You have $V = \{\text{all bounded measurable functions on }\mathbb R\}$. Indeed, assume $f\in V$ is unbounded. Then there exists a sequence $(x_n)\subset\mathbb R$ such that $|f(x_n)|\ge 2^n$. We can assume $x_n\neq x_m$ for $n\neq m$. Now, put $\mu := \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\delta_{x_n}$, where $\delta_x$ denotes the Dirac measure at $x$. Then
$$
\int |f|\,d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\int |f|\,d\delta_{x_n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}|f(x_n)| = \infty.
$$

Comment: Ok. So, there is a map $V\to L^\infty$. Is it the identity? How about the other questions?

Comment: What is $L^\infty$? Note that $L^\infty$ always needs a measure to be defined.

Comment: Question No 2 in original post: Yes, $(V,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is a Banach space. You should be able to answer the third question yourself.

Comment: $L^\infty$ with respect to Lebesgue measure, of course. These are the essentially bounded  measurable functions. Here, due to the Dirac measures, the functions need to be bounded, not just essentially bounded. Thus, a priori,  there is a map $V \to L^\infty$ but it seems to be injective.

Comment: Of course, the identity map from $V$ to $L^\infty$ is not surjective.

Comment: Which essentially bounded measurable function, i.e., function that is bounded except on a set of measure zero, is not in the same equivalence class in $L^\infty$ as a bounded measurable function?

Comment: You are right. The thing is that it is not injective. You map $f\in V$ to $[f]\in L^\infty$. So, e.g., $0$ and $\chi_{\{1\}}$ are both mapped to $0\in L^\infty$.