# Functions that are integrable with respect to all probability measures

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, measurable-functions

I am interested to know which measurable functions are integrable with respect to all probability measures, i.e., all $f$, for which:
$$ \int \|  f \| ~{\rm d}\mathbb{P} < \infty,$$
where $\mathbb{P}$ is any arbitrary real valued probability measure.

I have come across this topic:
[Characterize functions that are integrable with respect to all probability measures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685723/characterize-functions-that-are-integrable-with-respect-to-all-probability-measu)

which says that all bounded measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}$ are integrable w.r.t. to any probability measure. So I assume this means all functions of the form $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is this correct? If so can anyone give me a proof why this is the case? (Or point me to a book with a proof)

Comment: You have terms "measurable" and "measure" without specifying a $\sigma$-algebra.  Did you mean the Borel sets?  Or perhaps you mean an arbitrary measurable space $(\Omega, \Sigma)$?  Can you prove it also in that case?

Comment: I have literally linked that topic in my question. So no, it doesnt answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see that a bounded and measurable function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is integrable with respect to any probability measure $\mathbb P$ on the real line. If $\mathbb P$ is such a measure, and we let $K=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\lvert f(x)\rvert<\infty$, then
$$
\int \lvert f\rvert\,\mathrm d\mathbb P\leq\int K\,\mathrm d\mathbb P=K\cdot\mathbb P(\mathbb R)=K<\infty.
$$

Comment: So that means that it essentially holds for any finite measure, since it only depends on the the measure over the whole real numbers to be finite

Comment: And is it only true for functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$? or also for functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: The converse is also true: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685723/characterize-functions-that-are-integrable-with-respect-to-all-probability-measu

Comment: Yes, with the same proof, any bounded and measurable function on $\mathbb R^n$ is integrable with respect to any finite measure on $\mathbb R^n$.